# Transfer ownership of a Python object to C++ code using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have an abstract class `Shape` (from C++ code) and I have made a wrapper for it so I can inherit from this abstract class in Python. Everything works great except some memory management issue. Python object gets created and destroyed while there is still a `ShapeWrapper` C++ object that's alive. Basically the object gets destroyed cause there is no reference to it in Python, but there is a reference to the wrapper class in C++ so my thought was that the `wrapper` class increases the reference count on initialization and would decrease the count in the destructor when the C++ wrapper class `ShapeWrap`gets destructed. But it seems like that's not happening here. Here is some code:

The `Shape` class (in C++):

```
struct Shape {
    virtual inline string get_name() const = 0;
};
```

The `ShapeWrap` class:

```
struct ShapeWrap : public Shape, public wrapper<Shape> {
    string get_name() const override {
       if (auto py_func = this->get-override("get_name")) {
            return py_func();
       }
       return "Default String";
    }
}
```

I define the class this way:

```
class_<ShapeWrap, shared_ptr<ShapeWrap>, boost::noncopyable>("Shape")
     .def("get_name", pure_virtual(&Shape::get_name));
```

Now I have a little function here to take a Shape and print out its name:

```
void print_name(shared_ptr<ShapeWrap> shape) {
    cout << shape->get_name() << endl;
}
```

And in the Python land I do this:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Circle, self).__init__()
       print('Created')
    def __del__(self):
       print('Destroyed')
    def get_name(self):
       return "blah"

print_name(Circle())
```

This is what I get

```
Created
blah
Destroyed
```

But if I do this:

```
shared_ptr<ShapeWrap> create_shape(const object& cb) {
     return extract<shared_ptr<ShapeWrap>>(cb())();
}
```

And in Python do this:

```
print_name(create_shape(lambda: Circle()))
```

I get

```
Created
Destroyed
RuntimeError: Pure virtual function called
```

If I add cout in `ShapeWrap`'s constructor and destructor I get this

```
C++ Constructor
Created
Destroyed
RuntimeError: Pure virtual function called
C++ Destructor
```

Note that the pure virtual thing happens because the Python object is destroyed and thus doesn't have the override method so the wrapper goes and calls the base implementation which is a method to raise that RuntiemError exception.